# Magento checkout button available after click

Tags: javascript, magento, button, checkout

I've got a problem when it comes to the last step at checkout in Magento.

When the customer pushes the "Place Order" button, it disappears, just as expected, but after a few seconds it become available again for a while until the final redirection to the payment service is made.

This is not a huge problem, but customers could click the "Place Order" twice or more which, I guess, can cause troubles.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

See this short video for a demonstration: [Checkout button disappear/reappear](http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=10150188499599576)

Answer (score 0):

See: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/269181/